# How to check if button is clicked in JQuery using if else

Tags: jquery

I have a check box in Data table.I want to do edit and delete operation on a particular row by selecting ckeck-box.To fetch the check-box id I used Rowcallback function. When I select check-box and click edit ,the edit function must be called and when I click on delete delete function must be called.

This is how my code look like

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, o) {
     $('td:eq(0) #chkselect', nRow).on('change', function (e) {
          if (edit button condition) {
              edit();
          }
          else {
              delete();  
          }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're doing it on callback but, this is one way of finding out if it's checked or not.

```
$('#chkSelect').is(':checked')
```

or

```
$('#chkSelect').attr('checked')
```

But better way to do that must be defining functions directly on edit and delete buttons. I don't know how you populate the html back there, but you can define a generic function that gets line id as a parameter and continue from there. But again, it's entirely depended on your semantic at the front-end, and we don't know it.

Comment: I need logic for edit button condition.....when I click on edit button it should go inside the loop and perform edit() function

Comment: so were you able to see if it's checked?